# Spectral theorem in terms of multiplication operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have a problem attempting this task. Let $(\Omega , \mu)$ hasn’t got atoms. Let operator $A : L_2(\Omega , \mu) \to L_2(\Omega , \mu)$ be the operator of multiplication on real-valued function $\phi$. Let $\lambda \in \sigma_p(A)$ the question is which dimension could have space , generated by eigenvectors, corresponding this certain $\lambda$. I don’t know how to attempt this problem. I only have an assumption that the dimension can’t be higher than 1 (still I can’t provide it with formal explanations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... what does it mean to lie in the point-spectrum? If $f$ is an eigenfunction of $A$,
then $\phi(x)f(x)=\lambda f(x),$ implying for a.e. $x$ that $f(x)=0$ or $\phi(x)=\lambda$. Conversely, any $L_2$ function of the form $g 1_{\{\phi=\lambda\}}$ is, indeed, an eigenfunction. It follows that 
$$
\{ f\in L_2(\mu)|\lambda  f=\phi f\}=L_2(\{\phi=\lambda\},\mu),
$$
which is either trivial or infinite dimensional, since $\mu$ has no atoms.

Comment: Wait , if $f(t)$ is an eigenvector it is  enough to $\mu (\{x : \phi(x)=\lambda \})$ has a positive and what is $g$-function in $ g 1_{\phi = \lambda}$ ?

Comment: Also I didn’t understand how did we use the fact that there are no atoms in last Step?

Comment: If $\mu(\{\phi=\lambda\})=0,$ then $L^2(\{\phi=\lambda\},\mu)=\{0\}$. If $\mu(\{\phi=\lambda\})>0,$ there exists a sequence $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $A_1=\{\phi=\lambda\}$, $A_{n+1}\subsetneq A_{n}$ and $\mu(A_{n+1})\geq \frac{\mu(A_n)}{2}$ by the lack of atoms. Then, the family $(1_{A_n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: As for your first question... I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thank you